# Do VIEWS need a primary key in Galera?

Tags: mariadb, galera

We have a MariaDB Galera Setup, so do we require primary keys in a MySQL *view*?

It contains a complex select query with joins of tables and the values get updated. so do they replicate in a Galera DB setup properly or do we need to create primary Key for the views as well. Can anyone explain what's the behaviour of the Views in a Galera cluster environment.

Answer (score 2):

VIEW it is just a query (since mysql does not start support materialized views)

as a query - it doesn't store data and doesn't need to have any keys.
and view - does not replicate across a cluster and/or replicas, it just executed over local tables.

but underlying tables (included in a views query), yes tables included in this query must have.

Comment: thanks for explanation ; so u said VIEW is just  a query, but when I do select * from <view name>; I get table like structures with values as like in a table, so everytime I select * from view does that execute everytime and get me values or those values are stored in views ? ;  btw SHOW CREATE <view name> shows me the query and it a VIEW as well.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html just read all chapter

Comment: @SAGARNair - Shake this concept out of your brain:  "stored in views".  Data is stored in the tables referenced by the `VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

You say "and the values get updated"...  I assume this means that you are `UPDATEing` your `VIEW`?  Well, a `VIEW` can be syntactic sugar around a `SELECT` or an `UPDATE`.  The net effect of `UPDATE myView ...` is some row(s) in some table(s) get changed.  *That* is what gets replicated.  Each of the underlying table(s) needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.

A `VIEW` may *look like* a table.  Well, most `SHOW` commands *look like* tables.  That's just that "rows & columns" is a handy way to present information.